# Sorting a string list containing numbers and strings

Tags: sorting, delphi, tstringlist

I'm trying to sort a string grid filled with scores and strings like so:

[image]

via a sorted string list which is sorted by single columns from the grid called SUB 1, SUB 2, FINAL, TOTAL respectively (all these columns work except FINAL) and I'm not getting the results I need in the FINAL column.

I'm trying to get the column sorted like so, for example :

```
24
20
12
5
DNF
EXE
WE
```

but I'm getting this result instead (the result I do not want):

```
DNF
EXE
WE
24
20
12
5
```

In what way could I change my code to sort the grid as I want to sort it?

**My code:**

```
function Compare2(
    List   : TStringList;
    Index1 : Integer;
    Index2 : Integer) : Integer;
begin
  //comparer for custom sort used in SortLTSGrid
    if List[Index1] = List[Index2] then
        Result := 0
    else if List[Index1] < List[Index2] then
        Result := 1
    else
        Result := -1;
end;

procedure TfrmPuntehou.SortLTSGrid(var grid: TStringGrid; columntotal: Integer);
var
    TheList : TStringList;
    i,l,iCount,m:integer;
    const
    separator = ',';
const
    arrCodes:array[1..10] of string = ('DNF','DNS','WD','WE','DNA','OD','RD','EXR','EXE','PP');
begin
  //sorts grid largest to smallest according to one column

    //get grid row amount
    iCount:=grid.RowCount - 1;
    //create and fill the string list
    TheList := TStringList.Create;
      //fill the list
      for i := 1 to (iCount) do
      begin
        for l := 1 to Length(arrCodes) do
        begin
          if grid.Rows[i].Strings[columntotal] = arrCodes[l] then
          begin
          TheList.Add('0'+separator+grid.Rows[i].Text);
          end;
        end;
        TheList.Add(grid.Rows[i].Strings[columntotal]+separator+grid.Rows[i].Text);
      end;

    //try block to sort and write all strings in the list to the grid correctly
    try

       TheList.CustomSort(Compare2);

      for i:= 1 to (iCount) do
      begin
      grid.Rows[i].Text := TheList.Strings[(i-1)] ;
      end;

      //fill the row numbers
      for m := 1 to iCount do
      begin
      grid.Cells[0,m]:= IntToStr(m);
      end;


    finally
        TheList.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Use `TryStrToInt` to detect whether or not the values are integers, and if so, make sure that they are always ordered after everything else.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see that this function returns a boolean, should I check for true and false then?

Comment: I am confused. All columns contain the same elements. Yet it works for all but 'Final'? Are you wanting a different order for 'Final' to the others? In the table shown, foe example, I don't see how it could work for 'Heat 2' and not work for 'Final'

Comment: @dsm In short, yes. I'm not sure either why the FINAL column is full of it. The thing is all the other columns I sort by only have integer values, while FINAL has strings AND integers in it. The SUB and TOTAL columns are totals/subtotals respectively, the FINAL column represents the final stage/race of the evening for a specific group (I'm refining software I wrote for a local dirt oval racing club). So there might be a racer who didn't finish, the cell in the column for that racer would then have a DNF in it for example. And so those who did race should display above those who didn't

Comment: that's where the problem I mentioned above comes in

Comment: It's a two stage comparison. First of all compare whether or not the two values are int or string. Order accordingly. Only if both are int and both are string so you then compare the values as int or as string.

Comment: In that case just put a space in front of the string values would be the easiest way I would have thought.

Comment: @dsm If I may ask, how would the space in front of the string affect how it's sorted? Also should I perhaps add it like this ```TheList.Add(' '+grid.Rows[i].Strings[columntotal]+separator+grid.Rows[i].Text)```?

Comment: Have you tried to implement the algorithm I described? It's very simple. Or perhaps I have not explained it yet.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no, you haven't explained it to me yet.

Comment: " If I may ask, how would the space in front of the string affect how it's sorted" Letters come after numbers, but space comes before, and since you sort backwards, so to speak, this would put them at the end.

Comment: @Dsm punctuation comes before numbers too

Comment: @PrimeBeat Try to write a compare function that returns 0 if both values are ints, if both values aren't ints, and -1/1 if one is int and one is not. Once you can do that it is simple to extend it do what you want.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, true David, but spaces impact less on the visuals ;-)

Comment: @dsm It's not about the visuals, I'm referring to how text that begins with punctuation will be ordered

Answer (score 3):

You can use two different lists to store items, and two different sorting functions (because you want to sort them in different direction; numbers will be ordered as decreasing and strings will be ordered as ascending) to sort lists. Sort the lists separately, and than merge them.

Please consider @David Heffernan's performance warning.

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes;

var
 slStrings, slNumbers:TStringList;
 test:string;

function CompareForNumbers(
    List   : TStringList;
    Index1 : Integer;
    Index2 : Integer) : Integer;
 var
  val1, val2:Integer;
begin
  val1 := StrToInt(List[Index1]);
  val2 :=  StrToInt(List[Index2]);

  if val1 = val2 then
    Result := 0
  else if val1 < val2 then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := -1;
end;

function CompareForStrings(
    List   : TStringList;
    Index1 : Integer;
    Index2 : Integer) : Integer;
begin
  if List[Index1] = List[Index2] then
    Result := 0
  else if List[Index1] > List[Index2] then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := -1;
end;

begin
  slStrings := TStringList.Create();
  slNumbers := TStringList.Create();
  try
    slStrings.Add('EXE');
    slStrings.Add('WE');
    slStrings.Add('DNF');

    slNumbers.Add('5');
    slNumbers.Add('20');
    slNumbers.Add('24');
    slNumbers.Add('12');

    slNumbers.CustomSort(CompareForNumbers);
    slStrings.CustomSort(CompareForStrings);

    slNumbers.AddStrings(slStrings);

    Writeln(slNumbers.Text);

    Readln(test);
  finally
    slStrings.Free();
    slNumbers.Free();
  end;
end.
```

To use single list to handle @David Heffernan's performance warning, i've write this;

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes;

var
 slStrings:TStringList;
 test:string;


function Compare(
    List   : TStringList;
    Index1 : Integer;
    Index2 : Integer) : Integer;
 var
  val1, val2:Integer;
  val1integer, val2integer:Boolean;
begin
  val1integer := TryStrToInt(List[Index1], val1);
  val2integer := TryStrToInt(List[Index2], val2);

  if val1integer and val2integer then
    begin
      if val1 = val2 then
        Result := 0
      else if val1 < val2 then
        Result := 1
      else
        Result := -1;
    end
  else if (not val1integer) And (not val2integer) then
    begin
      if List[Index1] = List[Index2] then
        Result := 0
      else if List[Index1] > List[Index2] then
        Result := 1
      else
        Result := -1;
    end
  else
    begin
      if val1integer then
        Result := -1
      else
        Result := 1;
    end;
end;

begin
  slStrings := TStringList.Create();
  try
    slStrings.Add('EXE');
    slStrings.Add('5');
    slStrings.Add('WE');
    slStrings.Add('20');
    slStrings.Add('DNF');
    slStrings.Add('24');
    slStrings.Add('12');
    slStrings.Add('A');
    slStrings.Add('6');
    slStrings.Add('E');
    slStrings.Add('B');
    slStrings.Add('4');
    slStrings.Add('T');
    slStrings.Add('444');

    slStrings.CustomSort(Compare);

    Writeln(slStrings.Text);

    Readln(test);
  finally
    slStrings.Free();
  end;
end.
```

Comment: The ```TryStrToFloat``` functions aren't working. Delphi says ```there is no overloaded version of TryStrToFloat that can be called with these arguments```

Comment: AddStrings is giving me the same error as well

Comment: ok, so I gave the code you posted another try, it still works with the other columns that use this procedure (SUB 2 and TOTAL), but it still gives me the same result as I mentioned before with the strings on top and integers below it in the final column (I'm trying to achieve the opposite). But thx anyway

Comment: still no change, I get the same output, btw what would tmpFloat be (I don't see it assigned anywhere, although it is declared as a variable), funny that I actually tried that before I posted my previous comment, lol

Comment: @ssdk Nope, still no difference.

Comment: This is a really inefficient way to do it. It's very easy to write a compare function that applies the desired order when working with a single collection.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, i added your warning to my answer, thank you. PrimeBeat, i've updated my answer.

Comment: @sddk ok, I'll check out the new answer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, may you have a look at my new algorithm?

Comment: @sddk Still nothing, in fact things just got jumbled

Comment: @sddk Yes, that's perfect

Comment: @PrimeBeat What do you mean things just got jumbled? When you run the second program from the updated answer it does exactly as you ask. Can I ask you if you understand the compare function in the second program? It is important that you understand this and don't just paste it without that understanding.

Comment: @David Heffernan I do understand the compare function, it's that no matter what compare function I use I end up with the same output that I showed in the second example in the OP with numbers from smallest to largest.

Comment: @PrimeBeat Not true. You'd know it wasn't true if you ran the second program in this answer. Have you done that?

Comment: @David Heffernan ok, hold on, I'll make the second program and check it out

Comment: @David Heffernan So the example works perfectly, but not in the context of my program. While it does sort the integers above the strings, it sorts the integers in ASC instead of DESC order

Comment: So edit the code to apply the order you desire. I'm sure you can do that.

Comment: @PrimeBeat, The numbers you show us in OP are all integer but in your code you are adding a zero and a comma to make the value floating point number. You should change the "Compare function" to handle folating point numbers. Otherwise Compare function treat floating point numbers as they are string. Or you should give up adding zero and comma into values.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to sort times by shortest to longest first, then all text alphabetically (although that is arguable).

I would not modify the texts in the way that you do. Instead I would simply modify the comparer function and pass the texts 'as is'.

To test it I used a TMemo, but the principle applies to the tables - just copy the appropriate column to the string list.

```
function Compare2(
    List   : TStringList;
    Index1 : Integer;
    Index2 : Integer) : Integer;
var
  i1IsNumeric, i2IsNumeric : boolean;
  i1, i2 : integer;
begin
  //comparer for custom sort used in SortLTSGrid
  i1IsNumeric := TryStrToInt( List[Index1], i1 );
  i2IsNumeric := TryStrToInt( List[Index2], i2 );
  if i1IsNumeric and (not i2IsNumeric) then
  begin
    Result := -1;
  end
  else if i2IsNumeric and (not i1IsNumeric) then
  begin
    Result := 1;
  end
  else if i1IsNumeric then
  begin
    Result := Sign( i1-i2);
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := CompareStr( List[Index1], List[Index2] );
  end;

end;
```

Here is my test routine using a memo

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  iList : TStringList;
begin
  iList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    iList.Assign( Memo1.Lines );
    iList.CustomSort( Compare2 );
    Memo1.Lines.Assign( iList );
  finally
    iList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Your routine would be more like (although this I have not tested)

```
procedure TfrmPuntehou.SortLTSGrid(var grid: TStringGrid; columntotal: Integer);
var
    TheList : TStringList;
    i,l,iCount,m:integer;
    const
    separator = ',';
const
    arrCodes:array[1..10] of string = ('DNF','DNS','WD','WE','DNA','OD','RD','EXR','EXE','PP');
begin
  //sorts grid largest to smallest according to one column

    //get grid row amount
    iCount:=grid.RowCount - 1;
    //create and fill the string list
    TheList := TStringList.Create;
      //fill the list
      for i := 1 to (iCount) do
      begin
        TheList.Add(grid.Rows[i].Text);
      end;
    //try block to sort and write all strings in the list to the grid correctly
    try

       TheList.CustomSort(Compare2);

      for i:= 1 to (iCount) do
      begin
      grid.Rows[i].Text := TheList.Strings[(i-1)] ;
      end;

      //fill the row numbers
      for m := 1 to iCount do
      begin
      grid.Cells[0,m]:= IntToStr(m);
      end;


    finally
        TheList.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: So I tested this and this doesn't work at all (not on the SUB 2 or TOTAL columns either). It jumbles everything instead of sorting but thx anyway

Comment: This compare function is fine @PrimeBeat. If your code doesn't do what you want, then that's an issue with your code, not the code here.

Comment: @Dsm One minor point, doesn't the use of `i1 - i2` risk overflow?

Comment: @PrimeBeat there was an error in the original code I posted, but that is now corrected.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I guess so in theory, although in practice it would have to be a mistake involving at least one negative time. If all times are positive, as they should be, then no. The OP could check for that first.

Comment: @Dsm Better would just be to compare the values using comparison operators rather than using arithmetic

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes, I agree. Although it does lead to a much longer if..else list, and therefore is a bit less readable.

Comment: @Dsm I have a family of functions for this: `function CompareIntegerInc(Item1, Item2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if Item1=Item2 then begin
    Result := 0;
  end else if Item1<Item2 then begin
    Result := -1
  end else begin
    Result := 1;
  end;
end;
`